# Manage Certificates in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When managing certificates in Google Chrome settings->certificate manager->my certificates tab says:
You have certificates from these organizations it also wants me to import a certificate. It opens my home directory when I hit import button and it displays my home directory.

From seahores in ubuntu it says mymailaddress@gmail.com is a personal PGP key under the GNUPG keys section. When i use seahorse to export it I get an xxxxx.asc file and inside it is a private key when opening it with an editor.

What do you think the Chrome browser settings is looking for me to import into it's certificates tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looking for a PKCS#12 File

From Wikipedia:

> In cryptography, PKCS #12 defines an archive file format for storing
>   many cryptography objects as a single file. It is commonly used to
>   bundle a private key with its X.509 certificate or to bundle all the
>   members of a chain of trust.

I am guessing you will be importing your private and public keys, for authentication. In a private computing environment that would just be public and private keys for the user of the system.

If you wanted to you could also set up a CA (Certificate Authority) that is set up in a server environment, or use AD or LDAP, or a mail server which needed specific certificates to access them [the specific certificates].

You could actually grab a certificate off of the network, or transfer certificates to your machine, then import them into chrome, and you could access things which require those certificates.

Comment: @stevenhendo34 it looks like your certificate is in a hidden folder. If you are using nautilus press `Ctrl + h` to view hidden files and folders. From the command line (terminal) you can view the hidden files/folders with `ls -a`. Or since you have the path inside the details. The files should be in ~/.pki/nssdb/ hope that helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

List all certificates :
I get only one, which dose match what the chrome browse wants!
$certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
Certificate Nickname  Trust Attributes
SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
myemailaddress@gmail.com's StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Client CA ID u,u,u

List details of a certificate:
$certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L -n myemaiaddress@gmail.com
Two off the lines in the output listed bellow.
Other Primary Intermediate Client CA info not shown.
        Signature Algorithm: PKCS #1 SHA-1 With RSA Encryption
        Issuer: "CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Client CA,OU=Secure
then

Note: StartCom/StartSLL was were I got my free cert for my website on a cloud-computer. This is the one they gave me so I can Authenticate and then use the tools on their site. Oddly I can use their site fine without importing this into Chrome.

I don't know where to find this on my system or what the filename or filename extension would be. If I did want to import it to Chrome.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction--feel free to help more if you wish.
I am going to have to figure it out so I can back it up and save a copy off my hard drive encase of crash :(

Comment: Chrome uses a user-wide NSS store at the standard location of ~/.pki/nssdb

Comment: I am just wondering what you are trying to figure out. Are you trying to import your own certificates so that you can sign things individually? Or are you trying to just add the certificates because you can?